# Automatically set the sender in Outlook from the shared inbox (without inserting the shared mailboxes individually)

Tags: outlook, shared, sender

I'm looking for a solution so that I don't always have to manually select the sender of shared mailboxes.

I have one main user (admin@xyz.onmicrosoft). I set up this user in Outlook and the shared mailboxes were then set up automatically.

Now when I write a new mail, the main user is always selected as the sender.However, I have several shared mailboxes (info@, shopping@, etc.). If I am now for example in the inbox of the info@ and write a new mail, the sender should also be the info@.

I have already come across solutions where it is recommended to create the shared mailboxes individually. But I do not want to do that.

Is there another solution? In case of need I would also use a macro, but I haven't found anything suitable yet...

Answer (score 0):

@Marco

---

i think you can create Distributie list's
one for info@box
one for sales@box
one for shoping@box
give sent as rights to the user

add the head box member of the DL's

if you sent you can chage the from adresse
if you recive a mail wil be see in the Head box.
**goed luck**

Answer (score 0):

in case this is still an issue for someone:

You need to disable automapping for the shared mailbox and then add the mailbox as an additional mailbox to Outlook but use the users own credentials to connect to it

To disable automapping use PS - automapping is enabled by default:

Remove current mailbox permissin to the shared mailbox for that user:
Remove-MailboxPermission -Identity <*shared mailbox> -User '' -AccessRight FullAccess

Re-add it with automapping disabled:
Add-MailboxPermission -Identity <*shared mailbox> -User ' -AccessRight FullAccess -InheritanceType All -Automapping $false

To fix the send items going in the wrong mailbox send items folder:

1. on users pc
   add the following reg key needs to be added:
   HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\x.0\Outlook\Preferences
   DWORD  32 > DelegateSentItemsStyle value = 1
2. On Exchange server
   MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled needs to be set to false

To check the current status & change it in PS:
get-Mailbox <*shared mailbox>  | select MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled

If it is enabled you need to disable it
Set-Mailbox <*shared mailbox> -MessageCopyForSentAsEnabled $false